# How to parametrize Hypothesis strategy in @given

Tags: python, python-hypothesis

I'm testing a REST API, which can process different requests, e.g., dated and dateless. A request has a field called `request_type`. I'm wondering what's the best way to write test in hypothesis:

I can write two testes, one for dated, and the other is for dateless.

But for a common property, can I write one test which combine with `pytest.mark.parametrize`. The problem is how the request strategy uses that parameter `req_type` in `@given`.

```
@pytest.mark.parameterize('req_type', ['dated', 'dateless'])
@given(req=requests())
def test_process_request(req, req_type):
   # override the parameter req_type in req with input req_type
   pass
```

Is there a way to parametrize like `@given(req=requests(req_type))`? Or shall I just generate requests with dated and dateless randomly and pass into the test?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't do it all in external decorators, since they're (lazily) evaluated at import time, but you can use the `data()` strategy to draw a value inside your test function.

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('req_type', ['dated', 'dateless'])
@given(data=st.data())
def test_process_request(req_type, data):
    req = data.draw(requests(req_type))
    ...
```

Alternatively, if you can get the `req_type` from the `req` object, it is probably more elegant to generate either type and pass them into the test:

```
@given(req=st.one_of(requests(dateless), requests(dated)))
def test_process_request(req):
    req_type = req.type
    ...
```

I'd prefer the latter as it's a bit less magical, but the former does work if you need it.

Comment: Please update the answer with the correct syntax as many have probably suggested (edit queue is full)
`@pytest.mark.paramterize('req_type', ['dated', 'dateless'])`